# For every product in column, identify the user_id who has brought the product highest number of times

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a supermarket shopping dataset with two columns: Id, Products. 
Id is the unique ID of the customer, Products contain the items he has shopped for.
Table looks like this:

```
| S.No | ID          | Products           |
|----- |-------------|--------------------|
| 1    |        23   |     4,5,6          |
| 2    |        21   |     21,11           |
| 3    |        21   |     11,21,23,18,17 |
| 4    |        125  |     21,22          |
| 5    |        23   |     4,5,8          |
```

Now i want to identify who is the most shopped customer of each of the product like this

```
| Product | highestshopper |
|    4    |       23       |
|    11   |       21       |
|    21   |       21       |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `get_dummies` with `sum` before `idxmax`

```
df.set_index('ID').Products.str.get_dummies(',').sum(level=0).idxmax()
Out[145]: 
11     21
17     21
18     21
21     21
22    125
23     21
4      23
5      23
6      23
8      23
dtype: int64
```